# wpf listbox checkbox combination, really stuck

Tags: wpf, combobox, listbox, binding

I am trying to link the checkbox and listview together, and then use the binding method to set the path to the object in order to set the check-box IsChecked status in the listbox.

```
List<Test1> datas = new List<Test1>();

var data = new Test1 {Key = 1, Value = "Hello", IsSelected= true};
    datas.Add(data);
    data = new Test1 {Key = 2, Value = "Hello2", IsSelected= false};
    datas.Add(data);
```

What I need to happen is that if the checkbox is checked ( IsSelected is true ) then I need to populate with those values and then when I click and unclick the checkbox in the GUI I need it to also select the proper listeview item so I can get to the tag property.

This code below does not set the checkbox IsChecked.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstSwimLane" Width="225" Height="125" SelectionChanged="lstSwimLane_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                          Checked="CheckBox_Checked" 
                                          Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What do I need to change in order to set the check box to the value in the object?  I even tried INotifyChange etc...

Here is the object as well.

```
public class Test1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isChecked;

    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isChecked; } 
        set
        {
            if(_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

I am new to all this wpf, and I am stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with solving your problem? Did I understand your question correctly? Let me know if I need to clarify something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need this to work "three-way"? So setting any of the three properties

- `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`
- `CheckBox.IsChecked`
- `Item1.IsSelected`

will affect both of the other properties? Unfortunately, there is no such Binding in WPF so you're gonna have to do a little extra work.

**Update**
As pointed out by Robert Rossney, a much better solution for this is to bind

- `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` to `Item1.IsSelected`
- `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`

**Updated Xaml**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         Name="lstSwimLane"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         Width="225" Height="125" SelectionChanged="lstSwimLane_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                                Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                          Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"
                          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                              Path=IsSelected}">
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I don't see why you need multi-binding or event handlers or value converters.  You should be able to bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` in the `ItemTemplate`, and bind `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` to `Item1.IsSelected` in the `ItemContainerStyle`.  I haven't tried that myself (I don't have VS on this machine), but it sure seems like that should work.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: You may very well be right, I started out the other way and noticed that some combinations didn't work. I'll try it again when I'm at my computer. But there weren't any event handlers involved..

Comment: @Robert Rossney: I tried it and it worked great. Your solution was much better than mine so you really deserve the credit here, feel like you should have posted that as an answer. Good work anyway!

Comment: Glad it worked.  I try not to post answers that I'm not able to test - especially if my answer involves predicting how WPF will work, because there's always something I'm overlooking.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. The code works except that it only allows one selection at a time.  I need to have it where all check boxes can be selected or just one.  Right now it is only one.  It almost acts like a radio button.

Comment: @nitefrog: Updated my answer. Set `SelectionMode` to `Multiple` on the `ListBox`. Otherwise it only allow one item to be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, here is the markup for the listbox /  combox.  It will display horizontal.

Thank you all again for all you help as I greatly appreciated it.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         Name="lstSwimLane" 
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         Width="auto" 
         Height="auto"
         Background="Transparent"
         BorderThickness="0" 
         SelectionChanged="lstSwimLane_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                          Checked="CheckBox_Checked" 
                          Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```